# iPhone SDK: AdMob ads not appearing?

Tags: iphone, admob

I am trying to display ads from AdMob.

I've tried to follow the standard instructions for implementation. However, I am receiving this error message and no ads display.

AdMob: Did fail to receive ad in AdViewController

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a mistake on your end. When you get that message it means that AdMob doesn't have an ad for you or that your device is offline. This is a common situation. This is not a bug.

For aesthetic purposes, you want to set a background image (or color) on the UIView that you set to be the view of your AdViewController.

Hope that helps.